# parse HTML table from third party server (jQuery or PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, xml, json, parsing

I have a HTML table with sport results on a third party server that I would like to parse as a JSON or XML so I can grab me the values out of it...

I would prefer to do this with jQuery and already played around with `$.ajax` but I don't get it running :/

I also thought about a PHP script running on my server and doing something with `file_get_contents()` and parsing the result as JSON - without success...

Dose anyone have an idea - what is the best solution to do what I want? I need a thought-provoking impulse ;)

**My jQuery attempt:**

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "....",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Running in to an error:
[image: console output]

Comment: For cross-site, best to use a proxy script like you have mentioned. Literally all it needs to do is `echo file_get_contents($url)` and you can do the rest in Javascript if you want. But it sounds like what you are trying to do is parse HTML as XML or JSON. You can't do that!

Comment: @rjdown okay if I use a combination of PHP and Javascript what did you think is the best way to get the data out of the html table?

Comment: You should be able to use standard jquery functions on the HTML you receive from your PHP. e.g. $(data).filter('table')

Comment: @rjdown Oh yeah! That's nice! Thanks man!

Comment: No problem. Added as an answer for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments:

For cross-site content, make a proxy script using PHP. All this will need to do is grab the remote content and echo it out.

Your ajax request will then point to this script instead, and you will be able to parse the response using standard jQuery functions as if it were a normal page e.g. `$(data).filter('table');`

Answer (score -1):

Your 'dataType' is wrong? Shouldn't that be either 'html' or 'json' since i see you are receiving HTML content.

Comment: If I use 'html' or 'json' I get an error because cross-origin resource sharing is disabled on the target server...